# How do I prevent logging of 404 Not Found exceptions?

Tags: servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack and `ServiceStack.Logging.Log4Net`.  With the minimum config in my AppHost file:

```cs
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
LogManager.LogFactory = new Log4NetFactory(true);
```

Request handler not found exceptions (i.e. no route was matched) are magically picked up and logged.  I don't want to log these exceptions, but I can't figure out how to exclude them.

I've tried setting a custom exception handler:

```cs
ExceptionHandler = _appExceptionLogger.OnAppHostException;
```

but it doesn't appear to get hit for these exceptions.

Comment: This is not the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I searched in the ServiceStack source code for the string that was being logged and found that it was being logged by a [NotFoundHttpHandler class](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/e8f937e7a7c65332e8c95ca5ad72652ede53f726/src/ServiceStack/Host/Handlers/NotFoundHttpHandler.cs#L25)

This means that I can override the logging behaviour by adding a custom logger to my log4net config:

ServiceStack v3:

```xml
<logger name="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Support.NotFoundHttpHandler">
    <level value="OFF" />
</logger>
```

ServiceStack v4:

```xml
<logger name="ServiceStack.Host.Handlers.NotFoundHttpHandler">
    <level value="OFF" />
</logger>
```

Comment: Good find. I have added v4 to your answer too, as this may be relevant to others. Glad you found the solution.